# SSL Not Working in Apache2/Ubuntu

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to get my SSL working on apache2 with Joomla. However, I run into a connection timed out issue. I have done tons of research and am fairly certain that my code is correct. I've got my ports.conf file set up to listen on 443:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    # If you add NameVirtualHost *:443 here, you will also have to change
    # the VirtualHost statement in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
    # to <VirtualHost *:443>
    # Server Name Indication for SSL named virtual hosts is currently not
    # supported by MSIE on Windows XP.
    NameVirtualHost *:443
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

I've also edited my "default" file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

    DocumentRoot /var/www

    SSLEngine on
    SSLOptions +StrictRequire

    <Directory />
        SSLRequireSSL
    </Directory>

    SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1 +SSLv3
    SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:+SHA1:+MD5:+HIGH:+MEDIUM

    SSLSessionCacheTimeout 600    

    SSLCertificateFile /root/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /root/server.key

    SSLVerifyClient none
    SSLProxyEngine off

    <IfModule mime.c>
        AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert      .crt
        AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl         .crl
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

And my "default-SSL" in the same location:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl_access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

    #SSL Engine switch
    #Enable SSL engine for this virtual host
    SSLEngine on

    #   A self-signed (snakeoil) certificate can be created by installing
    #   the ssl-cert package. See
    #   /usr/share/doc/apache2.2-common/README.Debian.gz for more info.
    #   If both key and certificate are stored in the same file, only the
    #   SSLCertificateFile directive is needed.
    SSLCertificateFile    /root/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /root/server.key
```

And so on and so forth.

My problem is this: I am testing everything on a local server. When I enter a DNS, such as `https://mydomainname.com/`, I get a connection timed out error. However, if I instead punch in something like: `https://mylocalip:443`, it works but I get an invalid cert warning (which is to be expected because I am using a self-signed cert for testing purposes). Why am I unable to access my ssl with the name but am totally able to with the ip address?

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved. Upon pinging the server, I realized that it was going outside of my domain to access the site. I redirected and everything works fine.

Comment: Please mark question as awnswered in order to remove it from unanswered queue